# XAMPP / java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, mysql, networking, xampp, jetty

I was wondering if someone could help me out with an issue I'm having. I'm using a Jetty server and using XAMPP to connect to a MySQL server, which I'm accessing through PHPMyAdmin.

I have a class that essentially is meant to drop all the tables in a database and then add some more, with data.

The first time I ran it, it worked fine, and did what it's meant to do, but the next time, I'm getting errors like the ones below. If I try it with a different database on the same host, again, it works fine first time, but any additional attempts will not work.

Can anyone shed some light please?

[image: Errors in console]

Comment: Make sure no process is already connected to 0.0.0.0:8444

Comment: Thanks all, managed to fix the problem - there were still instances running that I couldn't see initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `Jetty` instance is already running. Try to stop it and then run your test again.

> If I try it with a different database on the same host, again, it works fine first time, but any additional attempts will not work.

This is happening because, I suppose, you are trying to start the server every time you start a test, but not closing after the test is done.

*You can now either stop your Jetty instance manually, using Task Manager, restarting your machine in order to be able to run tests again*

Comment: Instances weren't showing up in Task Manager, but I did realise they were still running from the IDE. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. It should be in Task Manager too :)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably ran Jetty server twice or port 8444 is being 'listened' by another application.

Answer (score 0):

Fire that command and find out which service is using that port

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```